# How to compute a group weighted average controlling for null values in Polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

A group weighted average without `null` is pretty straightforward

```py
import polars as pl

data = {"id":[1, 1, 2, 2], "a" : [2, 1, 1, 3], "b":[0,1,2,3], "weights":[0.5, 1, 0.2, 3]}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)
weighted_average = (pl.col(["a", "b"]) * pl.col("weights")).sum() / pl.col("weights").sum()
df.groupby("id").agg(weighted_average)
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  ┆ a        ┆ b        │
│ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ i64 ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞═════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1.333333 ┆ 0.666667 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2.875    ┆ 2.9375   │
└─────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

However, **column result from group containing `None/null` values would be invalid**.
This is due to the last term of the expression being not subsetted by the `null` mask
of column with `null` values.

*Example*:

```py
data = {"id":[1, 1, 2, 2], "a" : [2, None, 1, 3], "b":[0,1,2,3], "weights":[0.5, 1, 0.2, 3]}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)
weighted_average = (pl.col(["a", "b"]) * pl.col("weights")).sum() / pl.col("weights").sum()
df.groupby("id").agg(weighted_average)
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  ┆ a        ┆ b        │
│ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ i64 ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞═════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 2   ┆ 2.875    ┆ 2.9375   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 0.666667 ┆ 0.666667 │
└─────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

Value of column `a` group 1, should be equal to `2`: `2 * 0.5  /0.5` but is instead calculated
as `2 * 0.5 / (0.5 + 1) = 0.66`

How to get the right results ?
I.e. how to subset the denominator by other column mask when required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mask out the weights by the null value of the other column.

```py
data = {
    "id": [1, 1, 2, 2], 
    "a": [2, None, 1, 3], 
    "b": [0,1,2,3], 
    "weights": [0.5, 1, 0.2, 3]
}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)

# mask out the weights that are null in 'a' or 'b'
masked_weights = pl.col("weights") * pl.col(["a", "b"]).is_not_null()
weighted_average = (pl.col(["a", "b"]) * pl.col("weights")).sum() / masked_weights.sum()

(df.groupby("id")
 .agg(weighted_average)
)
```

#### Ouptuts

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ id  ┆ a     ┆ b        │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ i64 ┆ f64   ┆ f64      │
╞═════╪═══════╪══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2.0   ┆ 0.666667 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2.875 ┆ 2.9375   │
└─────┴───────┴──────────┘
```